# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while iterating sql resultSet with prepared statement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I am getting the below error while fetching the result set. I am using the jdbc thin driver(**ojdbc6**). The interesting part is, it is giving the error after processing the **10 rows**. I checked in some forums and found that there is some problem with  jdbc driver. I was wondering if I can do something with this driver(ojdbc6) itself!!

Would appreciate any help on this.

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST_SO_MANY_COLUMNS" 
   (    "COL1" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "COL2" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL3" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL4" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL5" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL6" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL7" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL8" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL9" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL10" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL11" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL12" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL13" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL14" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL15" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL16" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL17" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL18" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL19" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL20" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL21" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL22" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL23" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL24" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL25" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL26" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL27" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL28" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL29" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL30" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL31" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL32" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL33" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL34" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL35" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL36" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL37" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL38" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL39" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL40" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL41" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL42" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL43" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL44" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL45" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL46" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL47" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL48" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL49" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL50" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL51" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL52" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL53" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL54" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL55" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL56" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL57" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL58" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL59" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL60" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL61" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL62" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL63" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL64" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL65" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL66" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL67" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL68" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL69" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL70" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL71" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL72" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL73" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL74" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL75" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL76" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL77" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL78" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL79" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL80" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL81" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL82" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL83" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL84" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL85" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL86" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL87" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL88" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL89" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL90" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL91" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL92" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL93" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL94" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL95" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL96" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL97" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL98" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL99" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL100" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL101" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL102" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL103" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL104" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL105" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL106" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL107" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL108" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL109" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL110" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL111" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL112" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL113" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL114" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL115" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL116" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL117" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL118" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL119" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "COL120" VARCHAR2(4000)
   );
```

Table has around 200 rows and all columns are having values up to 4000 chars.

Query Format:

```
select "COL1","COL2","COL3" ......."COL120" from SRC."TEST_SO_MANY_COLUMNS"
```

Code snippet:

```
 Statement sel_stmt = connection.createStatement();
 ResultSet res = sel_stmt.executeQuery(query);
 res.setFetchSize(10000);
 ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
```

Not getting any error while fetching the resultSet. The problem occurs while iterating over the result set:

```
int count = 0;
if (resultSet.next()) {
    count++ ;
    //Do Something i.e. resultSet.getObject() .. and so on.. 
}
// Do something
```

The above iteration works fine for first 10 rows but gives the below exception after that. Stack trace  of the error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor.saveDataFromOldDefineBuffers(T4CVarcharAccessor.java:411)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.saveDefineBuffersIfRequired(T4CStatement.java:533)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.prepareAccessors(OracleStatement.java:1070)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.check_row_prefetch_changed(OracleStatement.java:3080)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.close_or_fetch_from_next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:321)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you share the Java code that causes this exception too please?

Comment: can you post your java code snippet where you process result set?

Comment: You are copying into an array that is smaller than the array you are copying from or you set up a too high number for how many places to copy(for example when there is nothing returned in query, have no initialised array, yet you copy)

Comment: I've checked OracleStatement class code - it seems buggy method somehow related to row prefetching mechanism. You could try to disable row prefetching entirely. See link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/oraperf.htm#i1059055

Comment: Added the code snippet in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a pretty old bug (4751145). It was reported in 2005 in the 10.2 driver. The 10.2.0.3 driver has the fix. My guess is that you're running with either 10.2.0.1 or 10.2.0.2.

The Oracle download page is here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

If you want to stick to the 10.2 codeline then you should move to the latest patchset which is 10.2.0.5. Note that the driver is backward compatible so you can also use the 11.2 or even 12.1 driver to connect to a 10g database.